# run a python script as administrator at startup on windows 10

Tags: python, windows, startup

I have a script that runs at startup, amd sometimes make some bcdedit modification that need cmd as administrator.
I tried method with registry and worked on win 7, win 8.1 but on win 10 didn't work:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]
"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"="~ RUNASADMIN"
"C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\cmd.exe"="~ RUNASADMIN"
```

Knows anybody another idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using Windows Task Scheduler? It has the option of executing on startup/login and I believe it should run as Administrator.

Comment: I consider this question an Off topic. Its better suited for https://superuser.com/

Comment: @wilbur i used with `run with highest privileges` but still can't run command in `bcdedit` ...